# Create array of objects in an object - Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

In the below code, 'info' object has a description, quantity, value. How to give them as an array(Indo property). How to retrieve in angular code.

```
details.customsDetail.itemDetails = {
                    currency : "2000USD",
                    weight : "lbs",
                    info : {                         
                        description : "descr",
                        quantity : "2",
                        value : "124",              

                     }

            };
```

Comment: what do you mean by ` How to give this in a array.`?

Comment: if the below resolved your issue accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean , indo property as array of objects?

```
details.customsDetail.itemDetails = {
                    currency : "2000USD",
                    weight : "lbs",
                    info : [{                         // How to give this in a array.
                        description : "descr",
                        quantity : "2",
                        value : "124",              

                     }]

            };
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign the object to a variable and later you can push it to an array.

```
var backUp = angular.copy($scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails.info);

$scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails.info = [];
$scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails.info.push(backUp);

console.log($scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails)
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.details = {"customsDetail":{"itemDetails":{}}};

$scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails = {
      currency : "2000USD",
      weight : "lbs",
      info : {// How to give this in a array.
          description : "descr",
          quantity : "2",
          value : "124",              

       }

  };

var backUp = angular.copy($scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails.info);

$scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails.info = [];
$scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails.info.push(backUp);

console.log($scope.details.customsDetail.itemDetails)
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```